# best design for a multilingual site in sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8

Just started with Sitecore. I'm working on a multilingual site, and would like to know the standard design for its information architecture. The site has common design for the 2 languages (English & Japanese). The pictures/ product offers would change for a few pages.

Users will choose the language from a dropdown on the site. The URLs would be

http://www.example.com/en/index.html
http://www.example.com/ja/index.html

After some research, here is a structure I came up with, to proceed.

```
Sitecore
 Content
  en
    index
    gallery
    products
  ja
    index
    gallery
    products
```

Before we start building, wanted to know, if there is any other better way for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless your JA and EN sites plan on having completely different structures, you don't need them.  Instead I would suggest something like:

```
Sitecore
    Content
        SiteName
            Home
                Gallery 
                Products
```

Then for each page you create an English and a Japanese version.  Sitecore will then include the language in the URL.

Comment: You mean to say, the URL will automatically become example.com/ja/gallery.html, event without such folder structure. Could you please point me to such example. I only could get for the one in question.

Comment: This is default behavior of Sitecore. As long as you've configured the languages in the sitecore/System/Languages node, it will try to parse the language out of the URL in the httpRequestBegin pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are perfectly valid. We've used both, in some sites even a combination of the 2.

Things to be aware of: if you build up e.g. navigation based on items in the tree, in the second version (language versions) you always need to check that each item has a version before you render it e.g.

```
foreach(var child in parent.Children)
{
    if (child.Versions.Count > 0) { //do something with child
```

If you go with your suggested approach then I'd recommend looking into the `<sites>` config as this allows you to direct one url to one node, the next to another.

Things like templates can be shared for each implementation. If you are setting up language versions then you'll need to consider `__standard values` in each language.

We often decided one or the other based on the difference between each site. If you have lots of pages in one language vs another then your first approach can be better. You can always have common content shared between sites however it then gets harder for editors to know where to edit: content/en vs content/ja vs content/common.